# Custom {{#eachIndex}} in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I'm trying to implement each with index: {{#eachIndex}}, but all code examples I found seems to be deprecated:

```
UI.registerHelper('eachIndex', function () {
    var withIndex = _.map(this, function(x, i) {
        x.index = i;
        return x;
    });
    return UI.Each(function() {
        return withIndex;
    }, UI.block(null), UI.block(null));
});
```

UI.block is undefined.

I have another snippet trying to pass parameters to template, but it also fails, so my guess is I got things totally wrong:

```
UI.registerHelper('clearfix', function () {
    return UI.With((function() {
        return {attributes:{class:this.col}};
    }), Template._clearfix);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first helper you don't need to explicitly call UI.each, rather what you want to do is return the data (along with the indexes) and iterate over them in the template with handlebars. For example:

```
UI.registerHelper('eachIndex', function () {
    var items = Items.find().fetch();
    var withIndex = _.map(items, function(x, i) {
        x.index = i;
        return x;
    });
    return withIndex;
});
```

And in the template:

```
{{#each eachIndex}}
    {{someProperty}}
    {{index}}
{{/each}}
```

Passing parameters to a template is as simple as:

```
{{> templateName var=someVar}}
```

Comment: Not EXACTLY what I had in mind, but fair enough. I did few changes on my code: renamed the helper 'Index' and call it like {{#each Index items}} (works for multiple types)

Comment: Sorry about that, sometimes it can be hard to tell what the asker's specific use case is, if that makes sense. Good that you got it working though :)

Comment: I think I read somewhere Meteor devs will add index to {{#each}} helpers eventually, so my question would become obsolete. But your answer could help some lost googler some day. Thumbs up!